# Inertia and related concepts

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, inertia

I recently learned about inertia that it is a property by virtue of which body resists change in it's motion.

I want to know what does "resistance to change in motion" actually implies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just means

$$\mathbf a=\frac{\mathbf F}{m},$$

which is another way of writing Newton’s Second Law.

Mass ($m$) is the quantitative measure of “inertia”. Acceleration ($\mathbf a$) is the quantitative measure of “change in motion”. The more mass an object has, the less acceleration is caused by a given force ($\mathbf F$). Greater mass makes it more difficult for something to change its velocity.